# How to get messages receive count in Amazon SQS using boto library in Python?

Tags: python, boto, amazon-sqs

I am using boto library in Python to get Amazon SQS messages. In exceptional cases I don't delete messages from queue in order to give a couple of more changes to recover temporary failures. But I don't want to keep receiving failed messages constantly. What I would like to do is either delete messages after receiving more than 3 times or not get message if receive count is more than 3.

What is the most elegant way of doing it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways of doing this.

When you read a message in boto, you receive a Message object or some subclass thereof.  The Message object has an "attributes" field that is a dict containing all message attributes known by SQS.  One of the things SQS tracks is the approximate # of times the message has been read.  So, you could use this value to determine whether the message should be deleted or not but you would have to be comfortable with the "approximate" nature of the value.

Alternatively, you could record message ID's in some sort of database and increment a count field in the database each time you read the message.  This could be done in a simple Python dict if the messages are always being read within a single process or it could be done in something like SimpleDB if you need to record readings across processes.

Hope that helps.

Here's some example code:

```
>>> import boto.sqs
>>> c = boto.sqs.connect_to_region()
>>> q = c.lookup('myqueue')
>>> messages = c.receive_message(q, num_messages=1, attributes='All')
>>> messages[0].attributes
{u'ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp': u'1365474374620',
 u'ApproximateReceiveCount': u'2',
 u'SenderId': u'419278470775',
 u'SentTimestamp': u'1365474360357'}
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've skimmed through boto documentation but could not find any clue for getting receive count of a message. Do you know where is it? By the way having a simple local database is my alternative way of managing this issue but first I would like to keep it simple -like getting receive count- if possible..

Comment: Can you add a syntax example? All I find is an empty dictionary when I read a message more than once and look at message_instance.attributes.

Answer (score 5):

aws has in-built support for this, just follow the below steps:

1. create a dead letter queue
2. enable Redrive policy for the source queue by checking "Use Redrive Policy"
3. select the dead letter queue you created in step#1 for "Dead Letter Queue"
4. Set "Maximum Receives" as "3" or any value between 1 and 1000

How it works is, whenever a message is received by the worker, the receive count increments. Once it reaches "Maximum Receives" count, the message is pushed to the dead letter queue. Note, even if you access the message via aws console, the receive count increments.

Source [Using Amazon SQS Dead Letter Queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSDeadLetterQueue.html)

Answer (score 4):

Other way could be you can put an extra identifier at the end of the message in your SQS queue. This identifier can keep the count of the number of times the message has been read.

Also if you want that your service should not poll these message again and again then you can create one more queue say "Dead Message Queue" and can transfer then message which has crossed the threshold to this queue.

Answer (score 2):

Get ApproximateReceiveCount attribute from message you read.
move it to another queue(than you can manage error messages) or just delete it.

```
foreach (var message in response.Messages){
       try{
           var notifyMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationMessage>(message.Body);
                    Global.Sqs.DeleteMessageFromQ(message.ReceiptHandle);
           }
       catch (Exception ex){
           var  receiveMessageCount = int.Parse(message.Attributes["ApproximateReceiveCount"]);
           if (receiveMessageCount >3 ) 
              Global.Sqs.DeleteMessageFromQ(message.ReceiptHandle);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be done in few steps.

1. create SQS connection :-
   sqsconnrec = SQSConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
2. create queue object :-
   request_q = sqsconnrec.create_queue("queue_Name")
3. load the queue messages :-
   messages= request_q.get_messages()
4. now you get the array of message objects and to find the total number of messages :-
   just do len(messages)

should work like charm.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but I am afraid this was not my case. I don't need len(messages) I need the receive count of a certain message.

Comment: yes, there is no defined function in boto to get the receive count. I would suggest you to maintain an local tuple which will have message id, number of count and message body. you load the messages from queue after certain time, check if id is present in the tuple , if yes, increase the receive count , if the receive count >3, you can remove the message. I saw the dir of message object and it doesn't have a receive count function. Hope it helps your problem.

Comment: This was the alternative solution I guess for now I have only this option. Thanks a lot..

Comment: A few comments: 
#1. A tuple would be a terrible was of tracking this, use collection.Counter which is a dict designed for exactly this problem. 
#2. Maintaining any kind of local count means you can't operate in a distributed manner, which is exactly the behaviour SQS facilitates. 
#3. In many instances the queue may be too large to load all the messages and you certainly wouldn't want a single worker receiving all of them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add some logic after comparing the 'ReceiveCount's, you can make use of this snippet as of 2023.

```
        sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
        response = sqs.receive_message(
            QueueUrl='queue_url',
            MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
            VisibilityTimeout=30,
            WaitTimeSeconds=10,
            AttributeNames=['ApproximateReceiveCount']
        )
```